# Troubleshooting Deployment of Build Artifacts to Another Environment Using Gitflow in Sitecore XM Cloud

Tags: xm-cloud

I have recently configured the Sitecore XM cloud environment for build and deployment. Following Sitecore's recommendation for a branching strategy ([Sitecore Recommendation](https://developers.sitecore.com/learn/accelerate/xm-cloud/pre-development/developer-experience/branching-strategy)), I've opted for the Gitflow setup.

In my setup, I have three environments: Development, UAT, and Production. The plan is to link the Development environment to the Development branch, UAT to the releaesxx branch, and then promote the releasexx to Production.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the promote option indicates that the environment is unavailable. Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this?

[image: Sitecore Branching Strategy]

Comment: I have the same issue. Presumably it is disabled at the moment as it's not working.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkGibbons! Initially, I could promote successfully when directing all branches to master (trunk-based). However, after transitioning to Gitflow by linking these branches, it no longer appears as active. I've since attempted to revert all branches to master, but the issue persists. Something seems to have shifted in the process.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully addressed this concern. In essence, when transitioning your website from one environment to another, such as from UAT to Production (PROD), it is imperative to configure the environment with the branch selection set to "None." This ensures that the environment is not bound to a specific branch, thereby affording you the flexibility to promote the build seamlessly.

[image]